# Scala how to remove item while matching other list itme

Tags: list, scala, filter

I have a 2 list of following class

```
  case class User(var userId: Int =0,
                var userName: String ="",
                var email: String="",
                var password: String ="") {
  def this() = this(0, "", "", "")
}
```

globalList of User class.

localList of User class.

I would like to remove/filter all items from globalList that are same userId in localList.

I tried couple of api with no success such as filterNot, filter, drop, dropWhile. Please advice me how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
val userIdSet = localList.map(_.userId).toSet
val filteredList = globalList.filterNot(u => userIdSet.contains(u.userId))
```

Answer (score 5):

The `diff` operator "Computes the multiset difference between this list and another sequence".

```
scala> val global = List(0,1,2,3,4,5)
global: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val local = List(1,2,3)
local: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> global.diff(local)
res9: List[Int] = List(0, 4, 5)
```